# UnboundID, LDAP jdk migration

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

How can I call a SSL connection on a:

```
com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.migrate.ldapjdk.LDAPConnection; ?
```

The following:

```
SSLUtil sslUtil = new SSLUtil(new TrustAllTrustManager());
LDAPConnection ldp = new LDAPConnection(sslUtil.createSSLSocketFactory(), getHost(), getPort(), getAuthid(), getAuthpw());
```

only works with:

```
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection;
```

However, I would like to stick to the migrated ldapjdk connection, if at all possible.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.migrate.ldapjdk.LDAPConnection, one of the constructors allows you to specify a com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.migrate.ldapjdk.LDAPSocketFactory instance that will be used to create the underlying sockets.  Further, you can use the com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.migrate.ldapjdk.JavaToLDAPSocketFactory class as an LDAPSocketFactory that wraps a javax.net.SocketFactory (of which javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory is a subclass).

The code to do this should be something like:

```
 SSLUtil sslUtil = new SSLUtil(new TrustAllTrustManager());
 SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslUtil.createSSLSocketFactory();
 JavaToLDAPSocketFactory ldapSocketFactory = 
      new JavaToLDAPSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
 LDAPConnection ldp = new LDAPConnection(ldapSocketFactory);
```

Note that for code you actually intend to use in real-world applications, you should probably use a better trust manager than one that blindly trusts any certificate presented by the server, since the TrustAllTrustManager doesn't do anything to help prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.  But the TrustAllTrustManager is a convenient first step to verify that you can get secure communication working before switching to some strong validation with something like the TrustStoreTrustManager.

Neil

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. And, yes the TrustAllTrustManager was just for testing purposes. I appreciate your time, thank you!